# NetworkX - remove node and reconnect edges

Tags: networkx

I have a node in a graph that acts as a sort of 'temporary connector' node. I'd like to remove that node and update the edges in the graph so that all of its immediate predecessors point to its immediate successors.

**Is there baked-in functionality to do that in `networkx`, or will I need to roll my own solution?**

Example:

I have a graph `1 > 2 > 3`. I'd like to remove node `2` and end up with the graph `1 > 3`.

Here's how I am currently doing it:

```
In [230]: g = nx.DiGraph()

In [231]: g.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3)])

In [232]: g.edges()
Out[232]: [(1, 2), (2, 3)]

In [233]: predecessors = g.predecessors(2)

In [234]: successors = g.successors(2)

In [235]: new_edges = [(p,s) for p in predecessors for s in successors]

In [236]: new_edges
Out[236]: [(1, 3)]

In [237]: g.remove_node(2)

In [238]: g.add_edges_from(new_edges)

In [239]: g.nodes()
Out[239]: [1, 3]

In [240]: g.edges()
Out[240]: [(1, 3)]
```

Comment: Not sure why all the answers assumed something to do with node degree. Aren't we talking about a generic graph here where we want to remove some nodes from a list of flagged nodes?

Answer (score 2):

I tried using mjvaak's answer on a huge complex Graph but it didn't work since it was creating edges with nodes that did not exist anymore. I fixed it by simply taking the edges from g0.

So I changed:

```
edges = g.edges(node)
```

for:

```
edges = g0.edges(node)
```

The fixed code is thus the following:

```py
def simplifyGraph(G):
''' Loop over the graph until all nodes of degree 2 have been removed and their incident edges fused '''

g = G.copy()

while any(degree==2 for _, degree in g.degree):

    g0 = g.copy() #<- simply changing g itself would cause error `dictionary changed size during iteration` 
    for node, degree in g.degree():
        if degree==2:

            if g.is_directed(): #<-for directed graphs
                a0,b0 = list(g0.in_edges(node))[0]
                a1,b1 = list(g0.out_edges(node))[0]

            else:
                edges = g0.edges(node)
                edges = list(edges.__iter__())
                a0,b0 = edges[0]
                a1,b1 = edges[1]

            e0 = a0 if a0!=node else b0
            e1 = a1 if a1!=node else b1

            g0.remove_node(node)
            g0.add_edge(e0, e1)
    g = g0

return g
```

Thank you mjkvaak for the solution! It just needed a slight modification for bigger graphs.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by a "huge complex MultiGraph"? Could you provide a reproducible example? I think the OP's solution is generic and should work all the time,

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, I was working on vascular anatomical networks that were proprietary to the research group I was working with, so I cannot share the data I was working with.

Also, I thought at the time that it was a Multigraph, but this was an error since it is only a undirected graph. I've edited the word Multigraph out of my post.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation and the update!

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution for DiGraph:

```py
import networkx as nx

g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3),(1,3),(3,4),(2,4)])

node = 2

for in_src, _ in g.in_edges(node):
    for _, out_dst in g.out_edges(node):
        g.add_edge(in_src, out_dst)

g.remove_node(node)

print(g.edges)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (3, 4)]
```

This is a simplified version of the solution by sauce_interstellaire for directed graphs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my solution is any better than Ryan already suggested, but I'm posting a function here, since it tries to tackle the question from a different perspective. They key is, that in a `graph 1 > 2 > 3` the node `2` has degree 2 (i.e. has 2 edges connected to it). Generally speaking, to simplify a graph in the sense of the question that was asked would then mean getting rid of all such nodes with degree 2. The below function does exactly that.

```py
def simplifyGraph(G):
    ''' Loop over the graph until all nodes of degree 2 have been removed and their incident edges fused '''

    g = G.copy()

    while any(degree==2 for _, degree in g.degree):

        g0 = g.copy() #<- simply changing g itself would cause error `dictionary changed size during iteration` 
        for node, degree in g.degree():
            if degree==2:

                if g.is_directed(): #<-for directed graphs
                    a0,b0 = list(g.in_edges(node))[0]
                    a1,b1 = list(g.out_edges(node))[0]

                else:
                    edges = g.edges(node)
                    edges = list(edges.__iter__())
                    a0,b0 = edges[0]
                    a1,b1 = edges[1]

                e0 = a0 if a0!=node else b0
                e1 = a1 if a1!=node else b1

                g0.remove_node(node)
                g0.add_edge(e0, e1)
        g = g0

    return g
```

An example:

```py
>>> G = nx.DiGraph()
>>> G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3)])
>>> list(G.edges)
[(1, 2), (2, 3)]

>>> g = simplifyGraph(G)
>>> list(g.edges)
[(1, 3)]
```

Comment: I don't think that this is a generalized answer. There can be many nodes with same degree or the graph can be more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general solution to the problem, where a user can supply any condition on a node to remove the node and recombine the graph. In a comment I have also placed some code that will allow a user to recombine edges with different weights.

```py
import networkx as nx
from itertools import combinations

def simplify_graph_with_predicate(G: nx.Graph, node_removal_predicate: callable):
    '''
    Loop over the graph until all nodes that match the supplied predicate 
    have been removed and their incident edges fused.
    '''
    g = G.copy()
    while any(node_removal_predicate(node) for node in g.nodes):

        g0 = g.copy()

        for node in g.nodes:
            if node_removal_predicate(node):

                if g.is_directed():
                    in_edges_containing_node = list(g0.in_edges(node))
                    out_edges_containing_node = list(g0.out_edges(node))

                    for in_src, _ in in_edges_containing_node:
                        for _, out_dst in out_edges_containing_node:
                            g0.add_edge(in_src, out_dst)
                            # dist = nx.shortest_path_length(
                            #   g0, in_src, out_dst, weight='weight'
                            # )
                            # g0.add_edge(in_src, out_dst, weight=dist)
                else:
                    edges_containing_node = g.edges(node)
                    dst_to_link = [e[1] for e in edges_containing_node]
                    dst_pairs_to_link = list(combinations(dst_to_link, r = 2))
                    for pair in dst_pairs_to_link:
                        g0.add_edge(pair[0], pair[1])
                        # dist = nx.shortest_path_length(
                        # g0, pair[0], pair[1], weight='weight'
                        # )
                        # g0.add_edge(pair[0], pair[1], weight=dist)
                
                g0.remove_node(node)
                break
        g = g0
    return g
```

Example Usage 1 (provided example):

```py
g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3)])
res = simplify_graph_with_predicate(g, lambda node: node == 2)
print(res.edges) # output: [(1,3)]
```

Example Usage 2:

```py
g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_edge("node_one", "node_two")
g.add_edge("node_two", "node_three")
res = simplify_graph_with_predicate(g, lambda node: "two" in node)
print(res.edges) # output: [('node_one', 'node_three')]
```